# Clion Qt missing DLL libraries

Tags: c++, qt, clion

For my final exam, I need to use Qt open source. At the moment I am using Qt 5.12.5 with Clion and Mingw73_64. I have already received a piece of code that works. The only thing that i needed to change are the Qt libraries. My code compiles but then it stops with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135). In the installation guide were there instructions to add something to the windows path. I think that is my problem but i don't have any idea how to solve that. If I use the debugger (c-make), it says that it cannot find the required DLL's.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Make sure the folder containing the `Qt` dlls are in the `PATH` environment variable.  Assuming you know where you installed Qt  (the full path of the folder containing the Qt dlls is needed) on your PC here is how to set the PATH environment variable: [https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work. I have set the Qt bin as well as the Qt lib and I keep getting the same error.

Comment: Maybe you have a space in the path and you need to quote it. Maybe you gave the wrong path to the folder containing the `Qt` `.dll` files. Maybe you need to reboot to apply the change?

Comment: If the PATH is setup correctly you should be able to open up a cmd.exe window and type designer and the Qt designer will start.